# SVN server side password security

Tags: svn, security, encryption, passwords

Our inhouse [Windows 2003 Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2003) hosts our company's SVN repository. I'm looking for a secure method, preferably encryption, for the server-side passwords. Right now, they're stored in clear text. Is there a SVN plugin or method that I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) is available in most SVN server binaries available for Windows.

Comment: After I got time to sit down and do some research on SASL I found everything I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without a doubt the most secure authentication system for SVN is SVN + ssh:// using certificate authentication for SSH. This makes brute force attacks statistically impossible, as an attacker can't use a dictionary.

This also makes [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks more difficult, as you can't intercept a password. Even if you have access to the server you won't have a user's private key, so this takes care of some threats posed by a malicious insider.

Answer (score 0):

If your company uses Active Directory, [that's an option.](http://www.sublimesvn.com/blog/2009/02/configuring-subversion-with-active-directory-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). The Enterprise Edition supports Integrated Windows Authentication (Active Directory Single Sign-On) out of the box. NTLM and Negotiate (SPNEGO) (NTLM and Kerberos) are supported via SSPI.